# In which countries is location sharing available?

Tags: location-services

[This Google support article](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7326816) makes it clear that location sharing is not available in all countries.

> You may get a warning when you open Location sharing. Common causes include:
>
> - You're in a country or region where you can’t share your location.

Which is the list of countries where location sharing is (isn't) available? I am looking for official sources from Google.

Comment: I don't think this is really an Android question as it is about Google Maps, and although it has an Android application, is an operating system agnostic service that is all managed server-side. This would be a more appropriate question for a Google developer forum, but looking into the Google Developer site, I cannot find any such list as being available to the public.

Comment: Besides what @acejavelin said, this may be subject to laws of the country and the agreement Google has with those which is outside the scope of this site

Comment: "*I am looking for official sources from Google.*" if the country list cannot be found, then pretty sure Google doesn't want to publicize it. Compare [Use the Phone app to record calls](https://support.google.com/phoneapp/answer/9803950) where there is also no list of countries, with [Country availability for Google Play apps & digital content](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2843119).

Comment: I arrived to this question while trying to find out why location sharing doesn't seem to work in a certain country. The only error message is "check your internet connection", but there is no clear indication that it is disabled on purpose by Google. However, it won't work for as long as having an IP address in that certain country.